# How can I list items in rails for options_for_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, drop-down-menu, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using `rails 4` and I'd like to list categories in a select drop down menu. How can I do that? I have a form that looks like so:

```
<%= f.select (:category_id), 
    options_for_select([ 
      ["Maths", 1],
      ["Physics", 2]
    ]) 
%>
```

but of course, the content has to be dynamic from database, so I tried the following:

```
options_for_select([ 
  @categories.each do |c|
    [c.title, c.id]
  end
])
```

but that outputs `#<Category:randomdigetshere>` if I try to get the same output outside of that `options_for_select` it works and the title / id is being displayed as it should.

What's the right way of doing it?

Comment: What is your `@categories`'s format?

Comment: @user2503775 it's like so: `@categories = Category.all`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
<% categories_array = Category.all.map { |category| [category.title, category.id] } %>
<%= options_for_select(categories_array) %>
```

or

```
<%= options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :title) %>
```

You can make it even shorter using [collection_select](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#option-tags-from-a-collection-of-arbitrary-objects)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `@categories`'s format is:

```
 @categories = Category.all
```

You can do:

```
options_for_select(@categories.map { |category| [category.title, category.id] })
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell you how many times I've looked this up and fat fingered my way around it.  Here's my take on it which includes:

- default text displayed in select drop down
- a method call on the instance which merges first_name and last_name attributes
- sets :selected so it is available when editing
- sets a class (useful for simple_form integration)

select_tag(:doctor_id, options_for_select(["Select doctor"] + @doctors.map{ |doctor| [doctor.full_name, doctor.id] },  :selected => :doctor_id), :class => 'form-control')

Remember that this needs to be wrapped in outputting tags i.e. <%= and %>

What options_for_select does is take an array and format into the native  html options tag format along with the selected attribute, etc.  What's going on here is that we initialize the array with a element titled "Select doctor" and then we append to that an array of items which look like ["Bob Smith", 1]